# How can I save my file image to a folder of the project in javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, base64, store, save-image

I want to save my image to my project's folder, the image that I have in two shapes (base64 or file).

```
        var base = canvas.toDataURL().replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");

        let file;
        const linkSource = `data:image/png;base64,${base}`;
        await fetch(linkSource)
          .then(res => res.blob())
          .then(blob => {
            file = new File([blob], "test",{ type: "image/png" });
            }
            console.log('base64  ',base);
            console.log('file  ',file);
```

Comment: Why would you need to `fetch` the source when you already have the binary data in base64 form in your `base` variable (on which note, don't use `var`, use `let` and `const`, `var` hasn't been modern JS for many years now)? Take that `base`, decode it, and write that to disk? (Also where is this running? Browsers only see URLs, not "folders" so if this is Node, just write the data to disk, and if this is the browser: we're going to need more details here to explain what you're actually trying to do)

Comment: I made fetch to get the file in two shapes, any one of them will be right I will use it,
Thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for your technical advice,
Now I want to save this file in my project's folder, I use javascript with flutter, but I don't use Node.

Comment: If you're not using node, the browser has no idea what "a folder" is so the best you can do is create an invisible `<a href="..." download="filename">` link that you then click using JS (lots of answers about how to do that on SO already) to trigger a save dialog, but JS cannot save files to a directory, because by design "web pages running in the browser" are not allowed to know anything about "files and directories on your computer".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on a project flutter with javascript, Now when I take screenshot for canvas, I want to save them as a file to appear in flutter,

Answer (score -1):

To speak at a high level, you need a server-side language like Node.js, PHP, Java to run the request through. These can then save files to the back-end's local folders, a folder on your server/computer, or to something like an s3 bucket remotely. All of this will require http request to avoid CORS restrictions.